# Import error in python when execution from different directories

Tags: python, thrift

I'm trying to run TestServer.py in thrift/test/py folder. When I execute it from test folder, it works properly. But when I execute it from thrift folder, it gave me following import error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/py/TestServer.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ThriftTest import ThriftTest
ImportError: No module named ThriftTest
```

Following is the line which cause the error.

```
from ThriftTest import ThriftTest
```

What is the reason for this? Complete python script can be found at https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/py/TestServer.py

Answer (score 1):

Your script is assuming that all of its modules will be in the `sys.path`. The current working directory is automatically placed in the `sys.path`, but the directory that the top-level script is in is not.

The usual solution to this is to build a distribution with `distutils` (or, better, the third-party module `setuptools`, and install it (with the usual `python setup.py install`). Then the script goes somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/TestServer.py`, while the modules go somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ThriftTest`, where `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/` is on your default `sys.path`.

Alternatively, you can use tools like `zc.buildout` or `pyInstaller` to create bundled-up applications that include their own libraries. Or you can use a shell script that does a `chdir` to your directory and then runs your script. Or build relocatable virtual environments and manually install the libraries into their site-packages. And so on. But really.

If you really need to be able to keep all the files splatted in the development directory but run them from anywhere, the way to do it is to add to `sys.path` at startup:

```
import sys
import os
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
sys.path.append(scriptdir)
import ThriftTest
```

Comment: I can't change the directory hierarchy, so I changed TestServer.py as above, https://gist.github.com/cdwijayarathna/3c8c7d12ca48764f5a73 . But still gets same result.

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna: Try printing out `scriptdir` to make sure it's what you expect. Under some circumstances, `sys.argv[0]` is just a filename instead of a relative or absolute pathname, in which case this won't work. Sometimes `__file__` can be used as a fallback in those cases, sometimes not. But let's see if that's your problem before trying to fix it.